# How to optimize linq query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have difficulty in getting an average score of students in each department. 
while every department there are many faculties, each faculty there are many courses, each course there are many students, and every student has a lot of value. 
the query that I have made, I get quite a lot of the time constraints that are required to display the same data capture. 
please help to optimize the query that I made this.

```
double TotalNilaiMutu = 0;
double JumSKS = 0;
double ipkMhs = 0;
double totalIPK = 0;

var queryDepartemen = (from so in StrukturOrganisasis
                        join dp in Departemens on so.ID equals dp.ID
                        orderby dp.ID
                        select new{dp.ID, so.Inisial, so.Nama}).ToList();

foreach(var departemen in queryDepartemen){
    var queryMayor = (from my in Mayors
                        where my.DepartemenID == departemen.ID && my.StrataID == 2
                        select my.ID).ToList();

    var queryMhs = (from ms in MahasiswaSarjanas
                    where queryMayor.Contains(ms.MayorID) &&
                        (
                            from sm in StatusMahasiswas
                            where
                                (
                                    from ts in TahunSemesters
                                    where ts.TahunAwal == 2013
                                    select ts.ID
                                )
                            .Contains(sm.TahunSemesterID)
                            select sm.NIM
                        )
                    .Contains(ms.NIM)
                    select ms.NIM).ToList();

    ipkMhs = 0;

    foreach(var nim in queryMhs){
        var queryNilai = (from kr in KRS 
                            join hm in HurufMutus on kr.HurufMutuID equals hm.ID
                            join kur in 
                                (
                                    from ku in Kurikulums
                                    join mk in MataKuliahs on ku.MataKuliahID equals mk.ID 
                                    select new {ku.ID, mk.Nama, mk.SKS}
                                ) 
                            on kr.KurikulumID equals kur.ID
                            where kr.NIM==nim
                            select new {
                                nilai = hm.NilaiMutu * kur.SKS,
                                sks   = kur.SKS
                            });

        TotalNilaiMutu = 0;
        JumSKS = 0;
        foreach(var ipk in queryNilai){
            TotalNilaiMutu += ipk.nilai;
            JumSKS += ipk.sks;
        }

        if(double.IsNaN(TotalNilaiMutu/JumSKS)) ipkMhs+=0;
        else ipkMhs += TotalNilaiMutu/JumSKS;

    }
    if(double.IsNaN(ipkMhs/queryMhs.Count())) totalIPK=0;
    else totalIPK=ipkMhs/queryMhs.Count();

    Console.WriteLine(departemen.Nama +" -> "+ totalIPK +" : "+ ipkMhs +" / "+queryMhs.Count());
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is, you don't have a single query. You're hitting the SQL multiple times, in a loop, which is most likely not a very good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding AsParallel()?

```
     var queryDepartemen = (from so in StrukturOrganisasis.AsParallel()
                    join dp in Departemens on so.ID equals dp.ID
                    orderby dp.ID
                    select new{dp.ID, so.Inisial, so.Nama}).ToList();

  foreach(var departemen in queryDepartemen.AsParallel()){
                    var queryMayor = (from my in Mayors
                    where my.DepartemenID == departemen.ID && my.StrataID == 2
                    select my.ID).ToList();

var queryMhs = (from ms in MahasiswaSarjanas.AsParallel()
                where queryMayor.Contains(ms.MayorID) &&
                    (
                        from sm in StatusMahasiswas
                        where
                            (
                                from ts in TahunSemesters
                                where ts.TahunAwal == 2013
                                select ts.ID
                            )
                        .Contains(sm.TahunSemesterID)
                        select sm.NIM
                    )
                .Contains(ms.NIM)
                select ms.NIM).ToList();
```

Comment: after I try, there is an error like this: 

NotSupportedException: The second of data source of a binary operator must be of type System.Linq.ParallelQuery <T> rather than System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable <T>. To fix this problem, use the AsParallel () extension method to convert the right data source, to System.Linq.ParallelQuery <T>. 


on line: 

queryDepartemen var = (from so in StrukturOrganisasis.AsParallel ()

Comment: what type is StrukturOrganisasis